# Tool to aggregate results from QC, Jira and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-plugin, hp-quality-center

We are using Atlassian Jira for issue tracking, HP's Quality center for tracking the tests and jenkins for running automated tests. Now all these platforms have results in forms of tables and graph projections. I have a requirement to create a tool which will get all the results in a single place.
I searched for different management tools which might have plugins for the above 3, however I couldn’t find anything which will satisfy the requirement. So, wanted to check if anyone is aware of any tool which will get all the results in one place?

Comment: Most likely you should create your own tool which will obtain data from databases, api and other existing interfaces.